# How to prove the following topological problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers and let $J$ be the topology for $X$ which has for a base the family $B$ of all half-open intervals $[a,c) = \{x:a \leq x <c\}$ where $a,c \in \mathbb{R}$ .

a)Show that the members of the base $B$ are both open and closed and further that the space $(X,J)$ is not connected.

I want to know is it enough to say that all members of B are open and closed if
[a,c)=[a,d] intersected with (z,c)q where z < a < c < d;
And the another part is difficult for me and I want help.

Comment: Here's a hint: To show that $[a,c)$ is closed you must show that its complement $$X-[a,c) = (-\infty,a) \cup [c,+\infty)
$$ 
is open, and therefore you must prove that its complement is a union of basis elements.

Comment: And, by the way, you should rewrite your question using MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It's pretty hard to read the way it is currently written, and this will deter people from helping you.

Comment: What are your definitions of: "open," "closed," and "connected"? Without those, you'll have a very hard time.

Comment: You'll also need your definition for a topological base.

Comment: This is called the Sorgenfrey line. Also called the lower-limit topology on the set $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

$$X \backslash  [a,c) = (\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\;[a-n,a)\;) \cup (\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}\;[c,c+n)\;)$$ is  a union of members of $B$, so $X$ \ $[a,c)$ is open. Therefore $[a,c)$ is closed.

Since $[0,1)$ and its complement are open and not empty, therefore $X$ is not connected.